# Why does SHA 256 sum change when writing image to a drive?

Tags: block-device, hashsum, disk-image

I've noticed that if I write an image via `dd` to a USB drive and then `sha256sum` that image; the sum changes. Why? It's never identical to that of the ISO.

I am running: `sha256sum /dev/sdb` (on the block device, not the partition(s))

Comment: Exactly what command do you run to get the `sha256sum` of the drive?

Comment: Are you comparing the partitions or the whole drive?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If your image is smaller than the USB drive then you need to make sure you read back just that size of data from the drive, otherwise all the remainder of the drive will be added into the sha256 and create a different result.

e.g.

```
$ ls -l tst.iso                                                                
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root  Jul  1 14:58 tst.iso

$ /usr/bin/sha256sum tst.iso
49bc20df15e412a64472421e13fe86ff1c5165e18b2afccf160d4dc19fe68a14  tst.iso

$ dd if=tst.iso of=/dev/sdg bs=1M
1024+0 records in
1024+0 records out
1073741824 bytes (1.1 GB) copied, 200.066 s, 5.4 MB/s
```

When we read this back we need to make sure we only read the 1,073,741,824 bytes we wrote.  In this case I know it's exactly 1024 blocks of 1M each so I can specify a `bs=1M count=1024`.

```
$ dd if=/dev/sdg bs=1M count=1024 | sha256sum
1024+0 records in
1024+0 records out
1073741824 bytes (1.1 GB) copied, 37.8798 s, 28.3 MB/s
49bc20df15e412a64472421e13fe86ff1c5165e18b2afccf160d4dc19fe68a14  -
```

Without the total bytes matching then the sha256 would be different.

Comment: What if you get +1 instead of +0 (i.e. 15207+1 records in)? How would that affect the calculation

Comment: The +1 means the data wasn't an exact multiple of 1M.  You may need to reduce the block size (bs=) to a number that's divisible by the file size.  The smaller the block size the slower it might run.